# What are the attributes of UIImage - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to make my storyboard programmatically so I put

```
var backgroundImage: UIImage!
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work

```
self.view.backgroundImage = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

**Question:** How do I access it, and set attributes to them? And what are the different attributes I can set to them

I know this is a simple question but bear with me please if you have any questions or need any clarification please comment them down below.

Comment: Try looking at the reference documentation for `UIImage`.

Comment: [Apple has fantastic documentation you can look at](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/). You can even turn Swift-only docs on.

Comment: @MtRoad I didn't know they had this thx man!

Comment: @Grapeapplesauce, one of the first things you should always do on a project is a research phase: find documentation, find example code, and figure out what the libraries can do so you can write less and better code. (Apple also provides a lot of example code too)

Comment: I highly recommend checking out an app called Dash. I've found it to be the fastest way to look up any language's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign a UIColor to an UIImage, which won't work.

If you just want a yellow background image, I'd suggest you try something along the lines of:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

[Apple has fantastic documentation you can look at](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/). You can even turn Swift-only docs on.